# How to change the attribute that a configurable product is configured by

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute

We want to to migrate our clients product data from M1 to M2. The client has been using one attribute for all of their sizes on all of their products on M1.

In M2 they would like to break this attribute out in to multiple attributes so they can use a different attribute per product type e.g instead of using the "size" attribute for everything they want to use "Size" "Shoe Size" "Waist Size" etc depending on product type.

So... 1 example:
Product is set up via configurable/simple products using the attribute "Size"

How can we change this "size" attribute to use the new attribute "Shoe Size" instead of "size"?

There will only be one size attribute associated per product but the attribute will differ depending on the product.

Can we do this via an import or a DB change? There are over 10,000 products so we want to avoid doing this manually going forwards.

Answer (score 1):

Let me google that for you :)

https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2_Demo/blob/master/Console/Command/Product/ImportConfigurable.php#L66-L75 uses the core magento product importer internally. Here you can see, that you could create an CSV file that uses `configurable_variation_labels` and `configurable_variations` to link simple products via `sku` and additional attributes from global scope.

Have a look at https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2/blob/master/Model/Adapters/NestedArrayAdapter.php#L40 to see how those fields should be munged together.